# Coredata indexing when adding and removing objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my CD model, I do have an Entity called Term.

```
Term attributes:
-highlighted
-index
-length
-location
-name
-value
Relationships
-statement
```

In terms, I store strings such as "a", "b", "23", "+". Then I also have a statement entity which I keep terms.

```
Statement:
Attributes:
-expression
Relationships:
-terms
```

Here's one STATEMENT made of TERMS:

x=23+a

I store the many terms to one statement relationship and terms are ORDERED.

Now, in my application 
**I would like to have the ability to tap on a term and select it and replace it with one/multiple term(s).** and make it added it to the statement.

If it's one term replacing one term, it's no big deal. However if user selects one term and tries to replace it with multiple terms, things become hairy. Since I do have ordered list for the terms, Coredata tries to add the term to the end of the list. I initially chose ordered list in coredata just to keep things ordered. Is there a way for me to insert the newly created terms in a specific index while keeping everything in coredata ordered?

I would appreciate any directions.

Comment: The values for the terms relationship will be returned in an NSOrderedSet - you need to insert your terms at the required index.

Comment: @Paulw11 sure, but I need to insert multiple terms for one index number. Does the ordered list pushes everything one index when I do that?

Comment: Also there's scenarios where user can select two terms at the same time and replace it with two terms.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the NSMutableOrderedSet insert method it takes a starting index and an array of objects to insert. Existing objects after the insertion point are moved up (so if you insert 3 objects at index 2 then the object at 2 is now at 5 and 3 is now at 6 and so on)

Comment: If the are replacing the terms the you simply use `replaceObjectAtIndex` or `replaceObjectsAtIndex`

Comment: @Paulw11 please add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Paulw11 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableOrderedSet replaceObjectsAtIndexes:withObjects:]: count of array (5) differs from count of index set (2)'

Comment: You can't replace more items than exist in the set.  You need to insert items if the count at the end will be greater than the count at the start